# Using bootstrap in multiple SASS files causes class override issues. What's a proper SASS/bootstrap structure?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I searched for a while, but couldn't find any similar issue to my very surprise.

I am using **SASS and Bootstrap** for a Drupal installation.
I have a simple file structure:

- *base.scss* - Provides Bootstrap and variable imports.
- *style.scss* - Imports the project's modules:

**style.scss**

```
@import "base"; 
@import "util";

@import "node";
@import "project";
@import "breadcrumb";
@import "menu";
```

So of course, all these `[above].scss` are existent and located in the same folder.

**My goal**

- I want to use bootstrap in all separate files: node, project, breadcrumb and menu, but only include bootstrap once.

**The problem**

1. If I want to `@extend .breadcrumb;` in one of the specified files *without `import "base";`*, the selector .breadcrumb can't be found.
2. If I `import "base";` in these *n* separate files, bootstrap selectors are included *n* times. This leads to incredible clutter, and makes overrides to bootstrap selectors complicated. For example, I want to change bootstrap's `.navbar-toggle`. If I'd do this in `node.scss`, it will be overridden by the then-imported *default* bootstrap selector in `project.scss`.

- Is there a proper way to include bootstrap only once and use it in
  several other files?
- I don't really understand why problem #1 exists whatsoever. SASS doc says:

> Sass will take the file that you want to import and combine it with the file you're importing into so you can serve a single CSS file to the web browser.

- So if I use the above-mentioned `style.scss` that imports bootstrap and *don't* import bootstrap in the modules, why is the compiler failing to resolve any bootstrap class? That doesn't really sound like *combining* imports, to me. Or am I missing some of the very basics?

**base.scss**:

```
/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.3.7 (http://getbootstrap.com)
 * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 */

// Core variables and mixins

@import "variables";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/normalize";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/print";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/glyphicons";

// Core CSS
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/type";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/code";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/grid";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/tables";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/forms";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/buttons";

// Components
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/component-animations";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/dropdowns";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/button-groups";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/input-groups";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/navs";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/navbar";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
// [...] other components

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/modals";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/tooltip";
// [...]

// Utility classes
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/utilities";
@import "../../bootstrap/stylesheets/bootstrap/responsive-utilities";
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [Sass starter kit](https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/starterkits%21sass%21README.md/group/subtheme_sass/7) which comes with Bootstrap theme?

From what I know they recommend your style.scss to look like this:

```
// Default variables.
@import 'default-variables';

// Bootstrap Framework.
@import '../bootstrap/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';

// Base-theme overrides.
@import 'overrides';
```

So my guess is that you have to import variables and bootstrap files into style.scss followed by additional files.

You can then add/edit variables and overrides, and you should be able to import additional files like node, menu etc. as well. They all should have access to bootstrap selectors and variables.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your question. I personally use an older setup with Bootstrap and Less.

Comment: I use the "less" starterkit of the Drupal 8 Bootstrap base theme, specified in https://sevaa.com/blog/build-drupal-8-bootstrap-subtheme-sass/.

My bootstrap files and variables are imported in _base.scss_, which is imported by _style.scss_ which imports all modules. These won't work w/o import statements. I also tried to import a new 'test.scss' in _base.scss_ (test.scss doesn't import _base.scss_). Result: `The selector ".breadcrumb" was not found.`

In _style.scss_ it's possible to use bootstrap variables and selectors. Only the imported files don't have access.

Comment: Hmm it sounds like there's a problem with your base.scss. Did you try importing bootstrap and variables directly to style.scss without base file and checking if variables and selectors work in modules? Or checking if variables and selectors work in base.scss itself? Also, any reason for not using SASS starter kit for D8?

Comment: I have no freaking idea why I chose to blindly follow the instructions in the tutorial and actually copy the less starterkit... But I don't think it's a big problem since the files and concept should be nearly the same, since my current setup is built on [Bootstrap SASS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) source files.

If you re-read my above "test.scss" scenario, I already tried your suggestion to import directly to style (well, I imported another module in base.scss, which is basically the same), unfortunately without success. 

I will include base.scss in the post.